Undefined offset: 1 in Livewire\resources\views\navigation-menu.blade.php Livewire 2.12
I am Updataing unread Messeges Count. and it works when there are unread messeges but give error when there is no unread messeges
I have Tried Try Catch that's all ..
I get the idea something is null but donno how to fix it as I am beginner in livewire
here is my app.blade.php
<body class="font-sans antialiased">
        <x-jet-banner />

        <div class="min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
            @livewire('navigation-menu')

            <!-- Page Heading -->
            @if (isset($header))
                <header class="bg-white shadow">
                    <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto py-6 px-4 sm:px-6 lg:px-8">
                        {{ $header }}
                    </div>
                </header>
            @endif

            <!-- Page Content -->
            <main >
                {{ $slot }}
            </main>
        </div>

        @stack('modals')
        @stack('scripts')


    </body>

here is Navigation view
 <div class="hidden space-x-8 sm:-my-px sm:ml-10 sm:flex">
                    <x-jet-nav-link href="{{ route('messenger') }}" :active="request()->routeIs('messenger')" class="relative">
                        {{ __('Messenger') }}
                        <span class="absolute -top-2 -right-2">
               <livewire:global-unread-count />
        </span>
                    </x-jet-nav-link>
                </div>
            </div>

the global-unread-count
<?php

namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use App\Models\ConversationMessage;
use Livewire\Component;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class GlobalUnreadCount extends Component
{
    public $unreadCount = 0;

    protected $listeners = ['globalNewMessage' => 'updateCount'];

    public function mount()
    {
        $this->updateCount();
    }

    public function updateCount()
    {
        try {
            $this->unreadCount = ConversationMessage::where('receiver_id', Auth::id())
                                                    ->where('is_read', 0)
                                                    ->count() ?? 0;
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->unreadCount = 0;
            // Log the error
            \Log::error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.global-unread-count');
    }
}

the view gloabal unread count
@if(isset($unreadCount) && $unreadCount > 0)
    <span class="inline-flex items-center justify-center px-2 py-1 text-xs font-bold leading-none text-red-100 bg-red-600 rounded-full">
        {{ $unreadCount }}
    </span>
@endif

app service provider boot
public function boot()
    {
        Livewire::component('global-unread-count', GlobalUnreadCount::class);
    }

my method inside chat component this updates the count
public function handleNewMessage($messageData)
    {
        // Check if the user is on the messenger page
        if ($this->isOnMessengerPage()) {
            if ($this->currentConversation && $messageData['conversation_id'] == $this->currentConversation->id) {
                // Update the messages in the current conversation
                $newMessage = new ConversationMessage($messageData);
                $this->messages->push($newMessage);
                $this->markMessagesAsRead();
            } else {
                // Update unread counts for other conversations
                $this->updateUnreadCountsAndLatestMessages();
            }
        } else {
            // User is not on the messenger page, just update counts
            $this->updateUnreadCountsAndLatestMessages();
        }

        $this->emit('chatUpdated');
        $this->emitTo('global-unread-count', 'updateGlobalUnreadCount');
        $this->emit('globalNewMessage'); // Add this line to emit a global event
    }

When I send a message and there is unread count , the error goes away or I manully make some feilds form db unread also goes the error ..
